# How to find SRID for random polygon?

Tags: postgis, srid

I'm testing spatial database performance on a dataset. Spatial objects in this dataset (stored as WKT in a flat text file) are random valid polygons which have vertex coordinates (x,y) where  100,000> x >0  and same for y.

Currently I'm having problem with inserting these data into PostGIS which has a geometry constraint check and I got an error like "violates check constraint "enforce_srid_polygon ".

So, how can I find/create a srid for my dataset ?

BTW: the polygons are valid polygons which are extracted from images by segmenting objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But the problems for me is I have to create a table in PostGIs and write the AddGeometryColumn, and so far I tried 4326 which didn't work for my dataset (stored as WKT in a flat file).

Comment: Can you show us the first few lines of the WKT?

Comment: Example WKT:   Polygon((40298 27160, 40299 27160, 40300 27160, 40301 27160, 40302 27160, 40303 27160, ..........................))

Comment: What is just before the closing bracket?

Answer (score 2):

You can query it with [Find_SRID](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/Find_SRID.html). So if your table looks something like:

```
CREATE TABLE ply
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  geom geometry(Polygon,4326),
  CONSTRAINT ply_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

then use:

```
postgis=# SELECT Find_SRID('', 'ply', 'geom');
 find_srid
-----------
      4326
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, I think SRID is same as WKID in ESRI parlance.
You can get a list of WKIDs from the following URLs:
[Projected Coordinate Systems WKID List](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp/pcs.htm)
[Geographic Coordinate Systems WKID List](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp/gcs.htm)

Cheers
Ujjwal

Comment: Thanks. But which one is appropriate for my dataset ?

Comment: That will depend on whats the extent of your test data. Do you know the corordinate bound for your data?

Comment: right srid is one which data is in. Knowing what you have is phase 1 , after that you can start to think converting it to something more suitable for you.

Comment: yes. The coordinate bounds are 0< x < 100K, 0 < y <100k

Answer (score 1):

The SRID if the polygon you are inserting has to match the SRID specified for that geometry column.  So whatever you used in the srid argument of [AddGeometryColumn](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html) is what you need for the INSERT.

Note that random vertices aren't necessarily going to give you valid polygons.